# Mutually exclusive method execution in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have two methods: `a()` and `b()`. While I'm fine with multiple threads accessing any of the methods at the same time (that is desirable), I do not want any threads to enter `a()` while `b()` is being executed.
How do I do that?

### Edit 1

Lets say there are 4 threads and `Thread 1` is accessing `A()`. What I want is all of the 4 threads should not use `B()`.

Comment: call `b()` at the end of `a()`

Comment: I don't think that's what is being asked.

Comment: Threads are not allowed to executed `a()` while `b()` is being used. Does `b()` modify the underlying resource? Are you looking for a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)?

Comment: `I do not want any threads to enter a() while b() is being executed` ***means*** **if Thread A is accessing `a()` then you don't want Thread B to use `b()`?** Is that what you want? If yes, please tell us what exactly you are trying to do. Maybe we can help you. I smell, something fishy is going on in your code

Comment: Yes that is what I want. And no, I'm not going to tell what I'm trying to do. The question was concise and precise.

Comment: I don't understand why you need this `if Thread A is accessing a() then you don't want Thread B to use b()` This is ODD. @assylias any comments from your side? I don't understand what exactly OP is trying to do

Comment: @FahimParkar My understanding: let's take 2 threads T1 and T2. If T1 in a(): T2 can execute a() and T2 can execute b(). If T1 in b(): T2 can execute b() but cannot execute a(). I don't know why the OP wants to do that but that does not really matter.

Comment: And what about when while `a()` is being executed? Is any other thread allowed to enter `b()`?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn The question, as it is worded, allows it.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn : I asked `means if Thread A is accessing a() then you don't want Thread B to use b()`, he said `YES`. If `A()` is used by any thread `B()` should not be used by any other threads.

Comment: @milan It would help if you clarified your goal. Do you want `a()` and `b()` to be mutually exclusive? Can a thread enter `b()` while another is in `a()`?

Comment: @assylias : OP will not tell his goal. Check his reply. `And no, I'm not going to tell what I'm trying to do. The question was concise and precise.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**CHECK UPDATE at the bottom** - I don't think this approach can work. Leaving it for information.

---

You could use a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

- if a thread is in `b()`, a thread trying to execute `a()` will block until the execution of `b()` is over.
- if a thread is in `b()` and a second thread tries to run `b()` it will be able to
- if 2 threads execute `a()` while `b()` is not being executed both will run

Note: once a thread is in `a()` and has passed the "semaphore test", another thread can start running `b()` before the end of `a()`

The principle should work but I have not tested it.

```
private final Semaphore inB = new Semaphore(1);

public void a() throws InterruptedException {
    inB.acquire(); //blocks until no thread is in b any longer
    //now we are good to go and execute a()
    //release the semaphore immediately for other threads who want to run a()
    inB.release(); 
    //rest of your code here
}
public void b() {
    //does not block to allow 2 thread running b() simultaneously
    boolean needToRelease = inB.tryAcquire(); 
    //rest of your code
    //if the permit was acquired, release it to allow threads to run a()
    if (needToRelease) {
        inB.release();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Your intention is not clear and your question has been edited because one of your comments says that you want `a()` and `b()` to be mutually exclusive (many threads can run either `a()` or `b()` in parallel, but `a()` and `b()` should never be run in parallel). In that case, you can use the same logic with 2 semaphores `inA` and `inB`.

---

**UPDATE => BUG**

As pointed out by @yshavit in a comment to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14133694/829571), there is a race condition in the code in the following scenario:

- T1 runs `a()` and acquires `inB`
- T2 runs `b()` and fails to acquire `inB`
- T1 releases `inB`
- T3 runs `a()` and manages to acquire `inB` although T2 is running `b()`

It seems that this can't be achieved with Sempahores only. [This answer gives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14134638/829571) a better solution.

Comment: could you please see reply to my comment? I don't understand what OP is trying to do. **if Thread A is accessing a() then OP don't want Thread B to use b()**

Comment: What if the first thread passes `a()`'s semaphore lock and unlock. Context switch. Thread 2 jumps into `b()`. It starts executing `b()`. Context switch `A()` gets executed. Isn't this exactly the case we want to avoid? That a and b are executed in parallel?

Comment: @coding.mof I included that case in my answer. The original question states: "*I do not want any threads to **enter** a() while b() is being executed*". So once you have entered `a()` because no thread was running `b()`, you are fine.

Answer (score 3):

Exception handling ommitted for simplicity:

```
public class Test {
  private final Object lock = new Object();
  private int counterA;
  private int counterB;

  public void a() {
    synchronized(lock) {
      while(counterB > 0) {
        lock.wait();
      }
      ++counterA;
    }

    // do work

    synchronized(lock) {
      --counterA;
      lock.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  public void b() {
    synchronized(lock) {
      while(counterA > 0) {
        lock.wait();
      }
      ++counterB;
    }

    // do work

    synchronized(lock) {
      --counterB;
      lock.notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.concurrent.locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) is a Java package which contains several locks

in `a()`, [take a lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock%28%29) and [release it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#unlock%28%29) at the end of `a()`

in `b()`, do the same with the same lock

If you want to deal with asymmetric behavior you may use a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), a() is reader and b() is writer : several b() locks but several a() doesn't.

Comment: that is what synchronize will do and that is not what OP is looking for