# Java synchronization across methods

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, concurrency, synchronized

I am looking for a way to avoid the two methods from running concurrently, but not stopping one (or both) of them for running concurrently on their own. For example, in the code below, I must have method A run concurrently on the same object, but method B should block until there are no threads running Method A. Similarly, A should block if B is running on any thread and B can run concurrently with itself.

```
public void A()   // calls from different threads on the same object allowed
{
  ....
}                // A should only block if B is running

public void B()   // calls from different threads on the same object allowed
{
  ....
}                  //B should only block if A is active
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133667/mutually-exclusive-methods

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple with an AtomicInteger, though it wouldn't be efficient.

```
static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
public void methodA() {
    for(;;) {
       int v = counter.get();
       if (v >= 0 && counter.compareAndSwap(v, v + 1))
          break;
       Thread.yield();
    }

    try {
      // do something
    } finally {
      counter.decrementAndGet();
    }
}

public void methodB() {
    for(;;) {
       int v = counter.get();
       if (v <= 0 && counter.compareAndSwap(v, v - 1))
          break;
       Thread.yield();
    }

    try {
      // do something
    } finally {
      counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```